# Deploy custom task model Alfresco Community 5.1

Tags: java, spring, alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to deploy my custom workflow (with custom task model) following [Jeff Potts's tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html#business-requirements). All seems to work fine, until I try to initialize build-in Alfresco and login on it.

That's an extract of the output:

```
2016-07-08 11:49:52,163  ERROR [web.context.ContextLoader] [localhost-startStop-1] Context initialization failed
 org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.someco.scripts.GetReview] for bean with name 'webscript.com.someco.bpm.review.get' defined in class path resource [alfresco/module/someco-repo/context/service-context.xml];
```

And a lot of exceptions below.

I guess it is an error at `service-context.xml` file, but I don't know how to well-form that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future questions about this, solution was to download and install all dependencies using Maven.

Answer (score 2):

Verify that you have created the webscript class under the same package and with the same name as Jeff Potts because, in your log, spring doesn't found it. Or edit the class attribute in your service-context.xml

Comment: I found the solution. It is a kind of your response, solution was install all dependencies with Maven. Thanks :)